# Change the font color of a disabled select element only in IE-10 and above browsers

Tags: html, css, browser

Change the font color of a disabled select element only in IE-10 and above browsers 
Please find the below html markup :

```
HTML:
<select disabled="disabled">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
</select>

CSS :

select[disabled='disabled']{
    background-color:#FFF;
    color: #000; 
}
```

Comment: _Why_ do you need a browser-specific hack?

Answer (score 0):

You [can't use conditional comments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx?Redirected=true) anymore so the next best option seems to be:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* IE10+ specific styles go here */  
}
```

**Source:** [CSS Hacks for Targeting IE 10 and Above](http://www.limecanvas.com/css-hacks-targeting-ie-10/)

Comment: Can you paste your final CSS?